# kafka connector for elasticsearch error

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Hello I have a problem during the installation of elasticsearch connector for Kafka. I had followed this tutorial : 
https://sematext.com/blog/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-how-to/

The error when I try to start the connector in standalone mode is:

```
(org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:74)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:263)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:147)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:75)
```

I use an AWS EC2 small instance to test this connector.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you use the 3.2.0 branch like that tutorial mentioned? I suggest you try the 4.1.0 branch instead... Alternatively, if you download all of the Confluent Platform, building Elasticsearch Connect won't be necessary

Comment: I can t download the Platform, because I have installed Kafka on ec2 Free tier for an accademic project. Confluent provides the entire service, I have already Kafka with elastic search on another VPC, news only the connector. Now I try to see the other grandi.

Comment: EC2 free tier isn't preventing you from downloading and running Confluent OSS. In fact, it'll connect and work with your existing Kafka installation if you configure it to do so

Comment: It is a class path issue, try installing the full confluent oss platform.

Comment: So it is possibile install confluent and run only the connector for an existing kafka installation?

Comment: "So it is possibile install confluent and run only the connector for an existing kafka installation?" -> Yes it is.